# Installing Serial library in PyCharm

Tags: python, installation, pycharm

after PySerial library is installed: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adsjJ.png)

I try to Run a simple program, and it says that No module named 'serial' is found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOjn1.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because the location where this package is getting installed is not included in the PATH.

You can try:

Hover on the package name and click on install package pyserial.

OR

Go to settings->Project XYZ->Python Interpreter-> Click on + sign->search and install package from there.

OR

Include the location of installed package in the PATH variable.

Comment: Cool!!! second option done.